# How to change a window in screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, the question is really vague. Please pardon me. My requirements are something like this

User will enter some personal data on first screen (like Date of Birth, Gender). On next screen he will answer number of screening questions(total questions are 8). So instead of showing all questions on one screen, I want to create a small window/frame where I will show first question, once the user answers that question and clicks "next", he will go to next window which contains second question(But the screen is same). I just want to change middle portion of screen.

I am really not able to frame this question in a right way. But please ask as many questions as you can and if you have some information, please share. Thanks.

Comment: You are looking for a __form wizard__.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is iFrames, http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp to embed one HTML document within another. Another way of doing this would be to make a uniform CSS for all your pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at any custom UI widget like jqxTabs, for example: http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxtabs/wizard.htm

In the example above there's a wizard which is created using a tab UI component.

As you see when you insert a valid information at the first section the wizard allow you to go to the next one and so on.

There are different free widgets which can fit great too. For example [jQuery UI tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) is such widget.